# drracket big bang with on-mouse and to-draw

Tags: racket

so my problem is:
We would like to create a program using big-bang which initially draws a blank screen, but when you click the mouse it draws a circle at that position. When you click again, it should draw a new circle at the new position, and the old circle should disappear.

what should the to-draw, on-tick and on-mouse function be? How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The online book [*How to Design Worlds*](http://world.cs.brown.edu/1/htdw-v1.pdf) covers the basic ideas. It is a bit dated (2008) but the fundamental concepts are the same today and so is **most** of the software.